# ARMv7: Is there a way to branch with link from a register?

Tags: assembly, arm

In ARMv7, I know there is the `bl` instruction which branches to an address and updates the link register to point to the instruction right after it. I also know that I can use bl to jump to labels referenced directly as follows:

```
bl example_label
mov r5, 0
example_label:
mov r5, 111
@ blah blah blah
```

However, when the address referenced by `example_label` is inside a register, let's say `r0`, I get an error when doing the following:

```
bl r0
mov r5, 0
example_label:
mov r5, 111
@ blah blah blah
```

Is there a way at all where I can perform a `bl` instruction using a register? Do I have to use some other method? Or is it completely impossible?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Updated code snippet as requested by tum_

```
push lr  # you need to store this
ldr r0, =example_label
blx r0  # overwrites existing lr.
mov r5, 0
pop pc   # return to saved caller and don't execute example label again...
example_label:
mov r5, 111
@ blah blah blah
bx lr # not blah blah, you need to return control to caller.
```

Comment: As always, ask a compiler.  In this case, compile a function that takes a function-pointer arg (and can't do tailcall optimization).  https://godbolt.org/z/d1ddG4s4h shows it using `blx r0`.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail why you think the updated code doesn't work?  It should, so there might be something else wrong with your test.  A [mcve] would be best.  You talk in comments about `Default_handler` but there's no such thing in the code you've shown us, so we can't really understand.

Comment: You need `bx lr` to make 'example_label' a sub-routine at the **END**.  But then when returning to `mov r5, #0`, you will again run 'example_label'.  You need to control the flow at the ends of the snippets.  `blx r0` is correct.  The 'x' is to take care of thumb interworking, which is historical baggage for ARMv7.  'Thumb2' makes 'interworking' obsolete... but it is the way to jump to a register and allows pure 32bit ARM mode which is for backwards compatibility.

Comment: why use ldr r0, blx r0 when you can just bl example_label?

Comment: you need to know if the function is thumb code or arm code btw and use the appropriate address.  all of this is documented by arm in the architectural reference manual for the armv7-a (or armv7-m depending on which one you are talking about).  Please posts the paragraphs you are confused about.

Comment: are you talking about armv7-a or armv7-m?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
blx r0
```

see https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0497/a/the-cortex-m0-instruction-set/branch-and-control-instructions/b--bl--bx--and-blx for full reference

Comment: Just tried it. The instruction right after it (`mov r5, 0`) ended up taking me straight to the Default_Handler label which just had `nop` and `bl Default_Handler`

Comment: `blx` is the right way to branch by address in register. Are you sure that `r0` register contains valid address ? and by the way `mov r5, 0` does not access memory and could not throw exception.

Comment: I did `ldr r0, =example_label` before `blx r0`, and in my first comment I was supposed to say `mov r5, 111` instead of `mov r5, 0`. Sorry about that. Either way, I still get thrown to the default handler

Comment: @Kookie Please shows us the full code fragment by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67357468/edit) your question.

Comment: @tum_ Sure thing

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to mark the label I wanted to jump to as a function type. Thanks for your help!